# FFMPEG WAV file not spitting out correct audio length

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, wav

I am piping the audio out with the 'attachment' header so that the result is immediately downloaded. With other formats, such as mp3, the duration on the downloaded file metadata is set correctly. With WAV tho, the duration reads 00:00, which makes it basically unusable by audio players like iTunes. Any help?

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.contentType('audio/wav');
    res.attachment('somefile.wav');
    var pathToAudio = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/pc7qp4wrf46t9op/test-clip.webm?dl=0';
    ffmpeg(pathToAudio)
        // .output(stream, {end: true})
        .toFormat('wav')
        // setup event handlers
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
        })
        .pipe(res {end: true})
});
```

Comment: ffmpeg only writes WAV duration if it can seek to the beginning of the file. When piping out, it can't.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the feedback. So the only solution is to write to a file and then send that?

Comment: It seems  so....